# Can i get the actual error returned in a http Request?

Tags: c#, api

at the moment i am call to a api as follows:

```
     public static string MyAPICall()
     {
        try 
        {

            var client = new RestClient(_uri);
            var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.GET,                                                    
             Resource=$"version1/status" };
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString();
        }
     }
```

Now if successful the statuscode should be OK , if not it wont be.
I do some checks as follows:

```
        var err = string.empty;
        var apicallResponse = MyAPICall();
        if (apicallStaresponse.ToLower() != "ok")
        {
          err =  "please contact your Administrator";
        }
```

How can i make things more meaningful , how can i return  what the actual error was , do need to return the
actual exception instead of HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString()?

Comment: What do you mean "actual" error? Specifically?

Comment: if the http response is not OK , what was the error ,, is it the response.Content or response.ErrorMessage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch the exception first. Instead of this:

```
try
{ ... some code with request ... }
catch
{ .. guessing what the error was here ... }
```

Use this:

```
try
{ ... some code with request ... }
catch(Exception exc)
{ .. now you have at least a message here... }
```

Then you have to know what API returns. There is a set of standard Http status codes with ones in 200s meaning OK.  Again check API you are using to see what response you may get.